# React-leaflet my entite doesn't hightlight when clicking

Tags: leaflet, react

it seems that my question and all related one have no answer on stackoverflow I will try here :
I've got the same issue than [this question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73181455/how-to-change-color-on-mouse-over-leaflet-react) but, there is no answer on it so I'll try ot my way :
I follow the [following tutorial](https://fmuchembi.medium.com/let-us-build-a-choropleth-map-using-react-leaflet-together-3245d30ac900) to create a chloroplète map with react-leaflet. Everything is doing great (the import of GeoJSON data, the colors etc.). but when I use the function OnEachFeature the highlight function doens't work.
When I click I have the informations than appaear but the border is not getting bigger like I configure it :

Before clicking on an entite
[image: Before clikcing on an entite]

Afeter clicking on an entite
[image: After clicking on an entite]

There is my code :

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet'
import data from  '../GeoJSON/data_exemple_PRA.json';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

function CarteRisquesPRACour() {
    const [onselect, setOnselect] = useState({});
    /* function determining what should happen onmouseover, this function updates our state*/
    const highlightFeature = (e=> {
        const { risques7, libelle } = e.target.feature.properties;
        e.target.setStyle({
            strokeWidth: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
        setOnselect({
            risques:risques7,
            libelle:libelle,
        });
    });
    /*resets our state i.e no properties should be displayed when a feature is not clicked or hovered over */
    const resetHighlight= (e =>{
        setOnselect({});
        e.target.setStyle(style(e.target.feature));
    })
    /* this function is called when a feature in the map is hovered over or when a mouse moves out of it, the function calls two functions
     highlightFeature and resetHighlight*/
    const onEachFeature= (feature, layer)=> {
        layer.on({
            click: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight
        });
    }

    const getColorRisVulne=(d => {
        return  d > 3500 ? '#530d0d' :
                d > 2750 ? '#530d0d' :
                d > 2500 ? '#69120e' :
                d > 2000 ? '#7f1810' :
                d > 1750 ? '#941d11' :
                d > 1500 ? '#aa2213' :
                d > 1000 ? '#c02714' :
                d > 750 ? '#cb3915' :
                d > 670 ? '#cf5315' :
                d > 650 ? '#d36e15' :
                d > 600 ? '#d78815' :
                d > 520 ? '#dba215' :
                d > 490 ? '#debd15' :
                d > 465 ? '#e2d715' :
                d > 430 ? '#d6d616' :
                d > 400 ? '#c7ce17' :
                d > 360 ? '#b7c517' :
                d > 320 ? '#a8bd18' :
                d > 275 ? '#98b519' :
                d > 210 ? '#89ad1a' :
                d > 190 ? '#6f9917' :
                d > 165 ? '#558415' :
                d > 140 ? '#3b6f12' :
                d > 110 ? '#205a10' :
                d > 0 ? '#06450e' :
                '#ffffff'; //le dernier on ne met pas son nom car le reste
    })
    const style = (feature => {
        return ({
            weight: 0.5,
            opacity: 1,
            color: '#000000',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor: getColorRisVulne(feature.properties.risques7)
        });
    });
    const feature = data.features.map(feature=>{
        return(feature);
    });
    return(
        <div className="totalCarte">
            <div className="">
                {!onselect.risques && (
                <div className='paragraphe infos_carte'>
                    Cliquez sur une zone pour avoir plus de détails
                </div>
                )}
                {onselect.risques && (
                    <div className='paragraphe infos_carte' >
                        {onselect.libelle} : {onselect.risques} €/ha
                    </div>
                )}
                <MapContainer center={[48.832,2.623]} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={false} >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    />
                    <GeoJSON data={feature}
                    style={style} 
                    onEachFeature={onEachFeature}/>
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default CarteRisquesPRACour;
```

Can someone help me understand why ?

**EDIT :** When I put mouseover instead of click the new style appears for less than 1sec and then diseappar

Comment: See working example here: https://codepen.io/hazmi/pen/JjoyONo. If you change `mouseover` to `click` and delete existing `click` processing, it works as you desire.

Comment: Thanks I use your code with my GeoJSON and it work perfectly aven with the click instead of mouseover. I don't really understand why so I'm gooing to dig up the problem In my code but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TomazicM , I modify my code so that it can work,

1. I transforme all my const into function
2. I put all the general function before my component like getColoreRisVulne ans style
3. I surrounded my  with {data&&( )}

the corrected code is in here :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {TileLayer, GeoJSON, MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet'
import data from  '../GeoJSON/data_exemple_PRA.json';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

let mapRef;

function getColorRisVulne(d) {
    return  d > 3500 ? '#530d0d' :
            d > 2750 ? '#530d0d' :
            d > 2500 ? '#69120e' :
            d > 2000 ? '#7f1810' :
            d > 1750 ? '#941d11' :
            d > 1500 ? '#aa2213' :
            d > 1000 ? '#c02714' :
            d > 750 ? '#cb3915' :
            d > 670 ? '#cf5315' :
            d > 650 ? '#d36e15' :
            d > 600 ? '#d78815' :
            d > 520 ? '#dba215' :
            d > 490 ? '#debd15' :
            d > 465 ? '#e2d715' :
            d > 430 ? '#d6d616' :
            d > 400 ? '#c7ce17' :
            d > 360 ? '#b7c517' :
            d > 320 ? '#a8bd18' :
            d > 275 ? '#98b519' :
            d > 210 ? '#89ad1a' :
            d > 190 ? '#6f9917' :
            d > 165 ? '#558415' :
            d > 140 ? '#3b6f12' :
            d > 110 ? '#205a10' :
            d > 0 ? '#06450e' :
            '#ffffff'; //le dernier on ne met pas son nom car le reste
    }

function style(feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: getColorRisVulne(feature.properties.risques7),
    weight: 0.5,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#000000',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
  };
}

function CarteRisquesPRACour() {
  const [onselect, setOnselect] = React.useState({});

  function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;
    const { risques7, libelle} = e.target.feature.properties;
    setOnselect({
        risques:risques7,
        libelle:libelle,
    });
    layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
  }
  function resetHighlight(e) {
    setOnselect({});
    e.target.setStyle(style(e.target.feature));
  }
  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      click: highlightFeature,
      mouseout: resetHighlight
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="totalCarte">
        <div className="">
        {!onselect.risques && (
        <div className='paragraphe infos_carte'>
            Cliquez sur une zone pour avoir plus de détails
        </div>
        )}
        {onselect.risques && (
            <div className='paragraphe infos_carte' >
                {onselect.libelle} : {onselect.risques} €/ha
            </div>
        )}
        <MapContainer
          zoom={10}
          scrollWheelZoom={false}
          maxZoom={14}
          center={[48.832,2.623]}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {data && (
            <GeoJSON data={data} 
            style={style} 
            onEachFeature={onEachFeature} />
          )}
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
export default CarteRisquesPRACour;
```

With that it works perfectly with a mouseover or a click.